# how to run a service independent of main thread when my app is visible?

Tags: android, service

I am trying to parse a xml from some source and store the results in database in a service that is  a alarm based service that runs every day at 6 am and it works fine when my app is not visible or is in background but when it is visible and the service try to parse the xml(at 6am) application stucks and after some time i get a ANR exception.

Thanx.

Comment: You did something wrong. You need to give more explanation / logs / code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `IntentService` instead of a `Service` class which in android runs in a separate thread as below:

```
    public class BackgroundService extends IntentService {

    public BackgroundService() {
        super("BackgroundService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //write code which yuou want to run in seperate thread
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to place a background/worker thread inside your services. Like this your remove the job from main thread and you should not get an ANR exception :)

Good luck,
Arkde